# Стеки фиксированного размера и очередь с max за O(1)

Tags: c++, алгоритм

При помощи очереди с нахождением максимума за O(1) надо обрабатывать миллиарды элементов. Чтобы программа работала быстрее, нужно придать фиксированный размер двум стекам, при помощи которых моделируется очередь. Как это сделать правильно? Мои попытки:

```
AmpQueue(int size){
    std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > v_temp;
    v_temp.resize(size);
    std::stack< std::pair<int, int>, std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > > s_temp(std::move(v_temp));
    s1.swap(s_temp);
    s2.swap(s_temp);
}
```

А вот и сама программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

// Класс для эффективного нахождения максимальной
// амплитуды на подотрезке
class AmpQueue{
private:
    std::stack< std::pair<int, int>, std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > > s1, s2;
public:
    AmpQueue();
    AmpQueue(int size){
        std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > v_temp;
        v_temp.resize(size);
        std::stack< std::pair<int, int>, std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > > s_temp(std::move(v_temp));
        s1.swap(s_temp);
        s2.swap(s_temp);
    }
    // Загрузка нового элемента в очередь с поддержной нахождения максимума
    void push(int new_element){
        int max = s1.empty() ? new_element : std::max (new_element, s1.top().second);
        s1.push(std::make_pair(new_element, max));
    }
    // Удаляет элемент из очереди и возвращает значение удаленного элемента
    int pop(){
        if(s2.empty())
            while(!s1.empty()){
                int element = s1.top().first;
                s1.pop();
                int max = s2.empty() ? element : std::max(element, s2.top().second);
                s2.push(std::make_pair(element, max));
            }
        int result = s2.top().first;
        s2.pop();
        return result;
    }
    // Получение текущего максимума в очереди за O(1)
    int max(){
        if(s1.empty() || s2.empty())
            return s1.empty() ? s2.top().second : s1.top().second;
        else
            return std::max(s1.top().second, s2.top().second);
    }
    // Проверка: пуста ли очередь
    bool empty(){
        return (s1.empty() && s2.empty());
    }
    // Загрузка в очередь последовательности из n чисел
    void load(int n){
        int value;
        while(n--){
            std::cin >> value;
            push(value);
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    int n, current, maximum, element;

    std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin >> n;
    AmpQueue q(n);

    // Загрузим в очередь первые n значение амплитуды
    q.load(n);
    // Выведем текущий максимум
    std::cout << q.max() << std::endl;

    // Загружаем следующий элемент последовательности и ищем максимум
    std::cin >> current;
    while(current != -1){
        q.pop();
        q.push(current);
        std::cout << q.max() << std::endl;
        std::cin >> current;
    }
}
```

Программа сначала крашилась при запуске, а после исправлений стала выдавать одни и те же числа. Возможно, этот код совсем плохой, потому что вчера я редактировал его уже только на идеоне. Поэтому показываю код на идеоне:

https://ideone.com/bJUpwL

Предполагаю, что проблема в том, что два стека уже заполнены нулевыми парами и имеют размер n, поэтому при добавлении новых элементов они укладываются сверху на существующие нулевые элемента. Из-за этого алгоритм работает неправильно (точнее, из-за условия empty).

Как все исправить?

Comment: Объясните, каким образом это работает за O(1), если каждый .pop()  перебирает все элементы?

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/stacks_for_minima

Comment: Потому что не перебирает. Просто при добавлении по одному элементу обрабатывается только один элемент.

Comment: Ага, прочел ссылку. Хитро придумано, теперь все понятно (в следующий раз ссылки на подобные алгоритмы лучше сразу указывать в вопросе), перебирает, но так, что каждый элемент из s1 (вход  очереди) перекидывается в s2 (выход очереди) только 1 раз.

Comment: Да, после конструктора s1 и s2 уже не empty. Если конструктор выбросить, то все работает. Насколько понимаю, на самом деле у Вас другой вопрос -- **"как сделать правильно работающий std::stack фиксированного размера, используя в качестве памяти уже 'сайзнутный' std::vector?"**. К сожалению (или счастью?) я не настолько хорошо знаю кресты. Другой вариант -- реализовать свой Stack, хоть бы и взяв за основу этот vector.

Comment: Уточните идею алгоритма. В частности - каким образом удаляется максимальный элемент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [`std::vector::reserve()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) вместо `std::vector::resize()`. Но в `push()` вам нужно контроллировать верхний размер в любом случае.

Ваш поправленный пример, не могу оценить насколько он работающий: https://ideone.com/uF09OU

Comment: Жаль, но все равно слишком долго работает :( Но алгоритм правильный. Прикольно, что после добавления std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false) скорость упала, хотя должно быть наоборот.

Comment: А вы попробуйте посимулировать без потоков ввода-вывода вообще.